# Chrome freezes when playing multiple mp4 files at once

Tags: google-chrome, video, localhost, freeze

I am trying to play multiple mp4 files on localhost via Chrome simultaneously.

Opening the first mp4 is no problem and the video begins to play.
But opening the second one and it will be frozen.
I can then either force refresh via ctrl-f5, or I can pause the first video,
either of which will allow the latter video to commence.

Also, forcing the latter video to commence in this manner, usually results in the former video to start freezing. It is like Chrome is having only one channel to play those multiple instances of the video and thats causing collisions.

How can I get multiple videos to begin playing on Chrome without this erratic freezing?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a coding question. You should post this to a Chrome support forum.